# Is the Whitney embedding theorem tight for all $n$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

Whitney's embedding theorem states that any smooth $n$-manifold $M$ can be smoothly embedded into $\Bbb R^{2n}$. In dimension 1 this is tight: the circle cannot be embedded into $\Bbb R^1$. It is a theorem that if $M^n \hookrightarrow \Bbb R^{n+k}$ is a smooth embedding, and $w(M)$ the total Whitney class of the tangent bundle of $M$, then $(w(M)^{-1})_k = 0$. Now consider dimension $m = 2^n$; there $w(\Bbb{RP}^m) = 1+a+a^m$, and hence $w(\Bbb{RP}^m)^{-1} = 1+a+a^2+\dots + a^{m-1}$. Hence $\Bbb{RP}^m$ cannot be embedded into $\Bbb R^{2m-1}$, proving tightness of the bound in these dimensions.

**Question**: Is Whitney's embedding theorem tight in all dimensions? (Let's restrict to compact manifolds.)

Note that the related immersion theorem, that there is an immersion $M^n \looparrowright \Bbb R^{2n-1}$, does not provide a tight bound for $n=3$, according to [this page on the Manifold Atlas project](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Hirsch-Smale_theory#Applications): every compact $3$-manifold immerses into $\Bbb R^4$.

Comment: More generally, the strongest *immersion* result is the [(now-proven) immersion conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immersion_%28mathematics%29#Existence), which states that every $n$-manifold can be immersed in $\mathbb{R}^{2n-\alpha(n)}$, where $\alpha(n)$ is the number of $1$'s in the binary expansion of $n$. Perhaps the strongest embedding result has a similar form.

Comment: Here is [a thread addressing the embedding question on MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/57549).

Comment: @Sal Thanks for the references. That answers my question; if you want to make your comments into an answer I would accept it. (I wonder if $\Bbb R^{2n-\alpha(n)+1}$ is a bound on embeddings; it seems like one should be able to take an immersion and massage it into an embedding one dimension higher, but I haven't yet been able to write down a proof.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As referenced in the comments, this [MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/57549/40804) gives the answer as no: every compact $3$-manifold embeds into $\Bbb R^5$, as [proved by Wall](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?r=1&pg1=CNO&s1=175139&loc=fromrevtext). The [Immersion theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immersion_%28mathematics%29#Existence) gives the optimal result for immersions: every compact $n$-manifold embeds into $\Bbb R^{2n-\alpha(n)}$, where $\alpha(n)$ is the number of $1$s in the $2$-adic expansion of $n$. $\Bbb{RP}^n$ cannot embed into any smaller Euclidean space, as seen by inspecting its Stiefel-Whitney classes.

Comment: "Every compact n-manifold embeds into $\mathbb{R}^{2n - \alpha(n)}$" is this true? It seems like you still need to require that the immersion is injective.